# Android enlarge center color with gradient

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I can not enlarge the width of a centeral color with a gradient.
The goal is:
[image]
Larger center with some color, and transparent on sides.

Usage:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/gradient_normal"/>
```

I tried many combinations with `layer-list`, but the result was not nice. One solution can be divide Layout to 50%-50% and set the first gradient from left to right (from transparent to color) and second right to left (from color to transparent), but this solution seems very complicated to me.

For example, this [generator](http://angrytools.com/gradient/?0_008000,50_ffff00,100_008000&0_100,100_100&l_0) cannot enlarge the center yellow color. (There is Android XML code generator.)

Any simpler solution? Thank you.

API21+

Comment: Without delving into gradient definitions (which would be more proper), did you consider 1 line tall 9-patch png with gradients on sides and transparent centre? Together with "tint color" on later Android APIs (I think tint works reliably (on 95+% of devices) around 19+) you can then produce any colour combination. About proper gradient-drawables: maybe you should post some core skeleton of your layout so one can better guess how difficult would be to change it to constraint-layout for example, or add list under as background. Also warn if you don't want to use for example constraint-layout.

Comment: use `ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory` and return `LinearGradient` from `resize(int width, int height)` method

Comment: Did you try the answer I have posted? Let me know if that was not the solution you had in mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope this is what you had in mind. I am using `layer-list`. I have used `"@color/colorAccent"` for either end. Change it to `"#0FFF"` to get a transparent color, which was required in the question.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:centerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:centerX="10%"/>
            <size
                android:height="100dp"
                android:width="50dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:right="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:centerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:centerX="80%"/>
            <size
                android:height="100dp"
                android:width="50dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Play around with the `android:centerX` attributes till you get what you want.

**OUTPUT**

This is what the drawable preview looks like with centerX at 10% and 80%

[image]

now with centerX at 60% and 40%

[image]

**EDIT**

To get the same effect in a layout that uses `match_parent` as the `layout_width` parameter, split the gradient into two drawables and set it as background for 2 different `ImageViews` or `FrameLayouts`

**left_gradient.xml**

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#0FFF"
        android:centerColor="#000"
        android:centerX="50%"
        android:endColor="#000"/>
</shape>
```

**right_gradient.xml**

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#000"
        android:centerColor="#000"
        android:centerX="50%"
        android:endColor="#0FFF"/>
</shape>
```

**In your Layout xml file**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/left_gradient"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/right_gradient"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Like with the previous case, tweak around with the values in `android:centerX` of both the gradient files to get the desired result

Comment: Thank you for your post. I would like to have width of whole `layer-list` `match_parent`. I use `layer-list` in `ImageView`, where is `android:layout_width="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="5dp"`

Comment: @t0m I have updated my answer to suit your need. Ping me back if this does not work

Comment: Thank you. I wrote above about the same solution: " One solution can be divide Layout to 50%-50% and set the first gradient from left to right (from transparent to color) and second right to left (from color to transparent)". I accept your answer for nice sample code.

Answer (score 2):

For someone who is still searching for answer...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:centerY="0.8"
                android:endColor="#60000000"
                android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="90"
                android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:centerY="0.2"
                android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
                android:startColor="#60000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```