# How to center the gradient color in android

Tags: android, gradient

Hi I am trying to gradient in android.
I am trying the following code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#EF5350"
        android:centerColor="#FFEBEE"
        android:endColor="#EF5350"
        android:angle="-270" />
</shape>
```

Result:

[image: OP image]

I want to increase the size of white in center. Please help me to solve my issue.

Comment: change your gradient angle to +270.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android enlarge center color with gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732392/android-enlarge-center-color-with-gradient)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this :**

[image]

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#EF5350"
                android:endColor="#EF5350"
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:angle="270"/>
            <size
                android:height="100dp"
                android:width="80dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="50dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#EF5350"
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:angle="270"
                />
            <size
                android:height="100dp"
                android:width="80dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Yes.. This what I want..!! Thanks @Vishva..!!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark as correct. :) Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify **type** inside the gradient tag,

For e.g. in my case I have defined **radial** for center gradient effect,

> android:type="radial"

I have created gradient shape (centergradietbg.xml) with center gradient effect, look it my code

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:shape="rectangle" >
>
>     <gradient
>         android:centerColor="#c1c1c1"
>         android:endColor="#4f4f4f"
>         android:gradientRadius="400"
>         android:startColor="#c1c1c1"
>         android:type="radial" >
>     </gradient>
>
> </shape>
> ```

Use this xml in your layout background using

```
android:background="@drawable/centergradietbg"
```